# How to set a maximum running time of a Hangfire job?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout, hangfire

When running a Hangfire job, there seems to be no maximum running time for a job before it will stop running. For example: the following code will run for hours with no problems, without changing any configurations.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("longJob")]
public IActionResult LongJob()
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => LongHangfireJob());
    return Ok();
}

[NonAction]
public void LongHangfireJob()
{
    Thread.Sleep(25200000); //7 hours
}
```

But now I am wondering how to build some configuration so the job will stop running after some time, and preverably be set on status failed if possible.

I already tried several options like `[JobExpirationTimeout(hours: 4)]` or `[Timeout(hours: 4)]` I found only or provided by ChatGPT. Also the following does not work:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => LongHangfireJob().WithTimeout(TimeSpan.Fromhours(4)));
```

Is there an option to do this (in the free plan of Hangfire), or is this simply not an option?

Also I am not talking about `CommandBatchMaxTimeout`, `SlidingInvisibilityTimeout` or `QueuePollInterval`, because jobs can still run past the timespan configured in these options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. But following 2 methods would be easy to develop.

1. One way to do this is to **use a cancellation token** that is passed to
   your job method, and periodically check the cancellation token
   inside the job to see if it has been cancelled.
2. You could **create a cancellation flag in a shared data store**  (such as a database or cache) that your job periodically checks. If
   the flag is set, the job can stop itself and exit early.